# decryption in mysql related query

Tags: mysql

I am encrypting and decrypting data using mysql.

Code to encrypt is

```
$query = "Update Users 
       set diary ='".openssl_encrypt(mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['content']),
                 "AES-128-ECB",$idkey)."' WHERE id =".$id." LIMIT 1";
```

Code to decrypt is

```
$query = "SELECT diary FROM Users WHERE id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_SESSION['id'])." LIMIT 1"; 
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,$query));
  $idkey = strval(mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_SESSION['id']));
  $diarycontent = openssl_decrypt($row['diary'],"AES-128-ECB",$idkey);
```

Now, when I decrypt data and, if the data has a newline, then it shows `\n`.
Eg: `Hi\nSneha here`.

How should I solve this?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: You're encrypting the escaped string. You should be encrypting, *then* escaping. More importantly you shouldn't be using manual escaping but **prepared statements with placeholder values**.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.